# nested functions are disabled error

Tags: c

I am trying to compile my C code but I'm getting this error, I've have relooked at all the code and I can't see what's wrong, but I don't know exactly what this error is as I have never seen it before, if anybody could help me, I would really apprecaite it.

```
C:\Users\Eahz\Desktop\scocl\workspace\xmc\/menu_functions.cpp(2034): error line: 2034 compiler: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
```

The code at the line 2034 is this:

```
    void looped_functions(void){
    //player options
    SET_CHAR_INVINCIBLE(pPlayer,godmode);
    if(pprotection){
        uint pos[4];
        GET_POSITION_OF_ANALOGUE_STICKS(0,&pos[0],&pos[1],&pos[2],&pos[3]);
        if(pos[0] == 0 && pos[1] == 0)
            FREEZE_CHAR_POSITION(pPlayer,true);
        else
            FREEZE_CHAR_POSITION(pPlayer,false);
    }

    if(rocketpistol){
        if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer)){
            GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(pPlayer,&tmp);
            GET_CAR_MODEL(tmp,&model);
            if(!IS_THIS_MODEL_A_HELI(model) && !IS_THIS_MODEL_A_BIKE){
                GET_CHAR_IN_CAR_PASSENGER_SEAT(tmp,1,&tmp_ped[0]);
                GET_DRIVER_OF_CAR(tmp,&tmp_ped[1]);
                if(tmp_ped[0] == pPlayer || tmp_ped[1] == pPlayer)
                    bone = BONE_LEFT_HAND;
            }
        }
        else bone = BONE_RIGHT_HAND;

        GET_PED_BONE_POSITION(pPlayer,bone,2.0,0.0,0.0,&play_tmp);
        GET_PED_BONE_POSITION(pPlayer,bone,100.0,0.0,0.0,&aim_tmp);

        if(IS_CHAR_SHOOTING(pPlayer)){
            GET_CURRENT_CHAR_WEAPON(pPlayer,&wWeapon);
            fire_projectile(wWeapon);
        }
        projectile_action();
    }

    if(superrun){
        if(!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer)){
            if(IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_LB) && IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_A)){
                APPLY_FORCE_TO_PED(pPlayer,true,0.0,100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,true,true,true,true);
            }
        }
    }
    if(superjump){
        if(!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer)){
            if(IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_LB) && IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_X)){
                APPLY_FORCE_TO_PED(pPlayer,true,0.0,0.0,20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,true,true,true,true);
            }
        }   
    }

    if(fastreload){
        SET_PLAYER_FAST_RELOAD(GetPlayerIndex(), true);
    }

    if(forcefield){
        float x,y,z;
        GET_CHAR_COORDINATES(pPlayer,&x,&y,&z);
        ADD_EXPLOSION(x,y,z,EXPLOSION_SHIP_DESTROY,10.0,false,true,0.0);
    }

    if(hydrolics){
        if(IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_X))
            {
                Vehicle PlayerVehicle;
                if (IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(GetPlayerPed()))
                    {
                        GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(GetPlayerPed(), &PlayerVehicle);  
                        if((!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_BOAT(GetPlayerPed())) && (!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_HELI(GetPlayerPed())))
                            {
                                if (IS_VEHICLE_ON_ALL_WHEELS( PlayerVehicle ))
                                    {
                                        APPLY_FORCE_TO_CAR(PlayerVehicle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f , 0.0f,0.0f,-60.0f, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
                                        //APPLY_FORCE_TO_CAR(PlayerVehicle, 0, x,y, z, spinX,  spinY,  spinZ,  0, 1, 1, 1); 
                                    }

                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    if(invisible){
    SET_CHAR_VISIBLE(pPlayer, false);
    }
    else{
    SET_CHAR_VISIBLE(pPlayer, true);
    }

    if(chaos){
        float dX,dY,dZ;
        GET_CHAR_COORDINATES(GetPlayerPed(),&dX, &dY, &dZ);
        ClosestCar = GET_CLOSEST_CAR(dX,dY,dZ, 15, false, 70);

            if( DOES_VEHICLE_EXIST(ClosestCar))
            {
                APPLY_FORCE_TO_CAR(ClosestCar, 3, 30.0, -20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 1, 1, 1);
                EXPLODE_CAR(ClosestCar, true, false);
            }
            GET_CHAR_COORDINATES(GetPlayerPed(),&dX, &dY, &dZ);
            GET_CLOSEST_CHAR(dX,dY,dZ, 30.0F, 1 ,1, &gameped);
            if(DOES_CHAR_EXIST(gameped))
            {
                if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(gameped))
                {
                    GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(gameped, &PlayerVehicle); 
                    APPLY_FORCE_TO_CAR(ClosestCar, 3, 30.0, -20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 1, 1, 1);
                    EXPLODE_CAR(ClosestCar, true, false);
                }
                else if(!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(gameped))
                {
                    if(!IS_CHAR_ON_FIRE(gameped))
                    {
                        START_CHAR_FIRE(gameped);
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    if(ragdoll){
        if(IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_LB) && IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_B)){
            if(!IS_PED_RAGDOLL(pPlayer)){
                SWITCH_PED_TO_RAGDOLL(pPlayer,20000,30000,false,false,false,false);
                SWITCH_PED_TO_ANIMATED(pPlayer,true);
                GIVE_PLAYER_RAGDOLL_CONTROL(GET_PLAYER_ID(),true);
            }
            else{
                SWITCH_PED_TO_ANIMATED(pPlayer,false);
                GIVE_PLAYER_RAGDOLL_CONTROL(GET_PLAYER_ID(),false);
            }
        }
    }

    //vehicles
    Vehicle pveh;
    if(vhelper){
        if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer)){
            GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(pPlayer,&pveh);
            SET_CAR_CAN_BE_DAMAGED(pveh,false);
            SET_CAR_CAN_BE_VISIBLY_DAMAGED(pveh,false);
            SET_CAN_BURST_CAR_TYRES(pveh,false);
            SET_HELI_BLADES_FULL_SPEED(pveh);
        }
    }
    if(carsonground){
        if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer)){
            GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(pPlayer,&pveh);
            SET_CAR_ON_GROUND_PROPERLY(pveh);
        }
    }

    if(bikefly){
        if((IS_CHAR_ON_ANY_BIKE(pPlayer)) && IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_R)){
            float speed;
            GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(pPlayer,&pveh);
            GET_CAR_SPEED(pveh,&speed);
            SET_CAR_FORWARD_SPEED(pveh,(speed * 1.05));
        }
    }

    if(nfs){
        if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer) && IS_BUTTON_PRESSED(0,BUTTON_R)){
            float speed;
            GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(pPlayer,&pveh);
            if((!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_BOAT(pPlayer)) && (!IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_HELI(pPlayer))){
                SET_CAR_ON_GROUND_PROPERLY(pveh);
                GET_CAR_SPEED(pveh,&speed);
                SET_CAR_FORWARD_SPEED(pveh,(speed * 1.02));
            }
            else{
                GET_CAR_SPEED(pveh,&speed);
                SET_CAR_FORWARD_SPEED(pveh,(speed * 1.02));
                }
        }
    }

    //weapons
    if(ammo){
        if(IS_CHAR_SHOOTING(pPlayer)){
            uint weapon,ammo;
            GET_CURRENT_CHAR_WEAPON(pPlayer,&weapon);
            if(weapon != WEAPON_GRENADE && weapon != WEAPON_MOLOTOV){
                GET_MAX_AMMO_IN_CLIP(pPlayer,weapon,&ammo);
                SET_AMMO_IN_CLIP(pPlayer,weapon,ammo);
            }
        }
    }

    //misc
    if(chat_thingy){
        int i;
        float pos_y = 0.875;
        for(i = 16;i >= 0;i--){
            if(i < 0) continue;
            if(!IS_NETWORK_PLAYER_ACTIVE(i)) continue;
            if(!NETWORK_IS_PLAYER_TALKING(i)) continue;
            if(NETWORK_IS_PLAYER_MUTED_BY_ME(i)) continue;
            GET_PLAYER_RGB_COLOUR(i,&r,&g,&b);
            set_up_draw(3,0.3,0.3,r,g,b,255);
            draw_text("STRING",0.70,pos_y,GET_PLAYER_NAME(i));
            pos_y -= 0.03;          
        }
    }

    if(GET_NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES_OF_STREAMED_SCRIPT("player_menuiv") != 0 && show_menu)
        menu_shutdown();

    //garage
    if(in_paint && IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_CAR(pPlayer)){
        if(menu[item_select].value != menu[item_select].extra_val){
            uint color1,color2,spec1,spec2;
            GET_CAR_COLOURS(pveh,&color1,&color2);
            GET_EXTRA_CAR_COLOURS(pveh,&spec1,&spec2);
            if(item_select == 1)
                CHANGE_CAR_COLOUR(pveh,(menu[item_select].value - 1),color2);
            if(item_select == 2)
                CHANGE_CAR_COLOUR(pveh,color1,(menu[item_select].value - 1));
            if(item_select == 3)
                SET_EXTRA_CAR_COLOURS(pveh,(menu[item_select].value - 1),spec2);                
            if(item_select == 4)
                SET_EXTRA_CAR_COLOURS(pveh,spec1,(menu[item_select].value - 1));

            menu[item_select].extra_val = menu[item_select].value;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 2034?

Comment: Is `looped_functions()` contained inside of another function?

Comment: You're probably missing a final closing brace on the previous function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ] before too long. Please learn how to produce an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  In this case, you'd take a copy of the file and ruthlessly chop out material that leaves the compilation error occurring.  You can chop out paragraphs of code.  You can chop out functions that compile.  You can chop out code after the erroneous line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `void looped_functions(void){` is inside some other function. You have likely a missing } somewhere in the function preceding `looped_functions`, e.g.

```
void another_func(void) {
  if(something) {
    if(somethingelse) {
       doit();
     // < missing a } here, causing looped_function below to be defined within 
     //this function
  }
}


void looped_functions(void){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing a } indeed !